# Creating a aws endpoint to accept json format with store it to DS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cicd

Create an endpoint in AWS where data can be sent in a JSON format which can be stored to a data store.

I think i can write a terraform code to create a Amazon API Gateway, lambda fuction to accept json format and store in DS.

What should i do to build a CI CD around this?
Any idea on this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways - for an automated way to provision infrastructure during your CI/CD pipeline, use [Infrastructure as Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_code).

You can use [Terraform](https://terraform.io/), [CloudFormation YAML/JSON](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-formats.html), [AWS Cloud Development Kit (CDK)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/home.html), [Serverless Framework](https://www.serverless.com/) (depending on your data store) etc.

If all you need is a Lambda, API Gateway and a serverless data store like DynamoDB, the quickest way to get set up in my opinion would be the Serverless Framework, however, all are viable solutions.