# AWS C# Lambda Functions Deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have joined a project where I have written AWS Lambda Functions in C#. I'm new to working with AWS and Lambda Functions. Does anyone know of a way of automating releases into AWS?  Can scripting be applied to releasing without a pipeline?  The only option I have found so far is to upload the code in a zip file.  Is there a better method  of deployment?

Comment: Yes refer to my answer from a few hours ago here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69509837/4800344

Answer (score -1):

Deployment Methods are plentiful.

You can use Terraform, it works well enough using an SDK in your language of chocie.

In-house to AWS, you have CloudFormation Templates which can be applied through CodeDeploy as part of a CodePipeline (since you mention c# you are using a docker deployment of lambdas, you may need a codebuild step.)

The next level up from that is SAM Templates, which I *believe* will handle a docker deployment of a C# lambda much easier than CloudFormation by itself would.

Finally you have the CDK (Cloud Development Kit) which puts infrastructre as a language, and allows you to program your infrastructure in most languages (I Do not know if C# is one of them - Typescript, Python are the two more popular ones to do CDK in) and I believe that can handle Docker deployment of lambdas as well.